# Identifying contiguous subsequences in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with a timestamp column (and a "seconds" column, fwiw). What I want is to count the number of contiguous blocks and their lengths, where contiguous means that subsequent entries differ by less than k seconds. In other words, I'm looking to count the gaps and the lengths of the runs.

The number of gaps isn't hard:

```
num_gaps = len(np.where(np.diff(np.array(df.seconds)) > k))
```

but efficiently counting the run lengths is stumpping me. Any suggestions?

This is easy, of course, with iterrows(), just not efficient.

Answer (score -1):

Oh, I'm being a dufus. The run lengths are just the differences in the gap array (including the 0 begin and len() end.